# On IOS device table disappear on swipe , scrolling and typing

Tags: html, ios, html-table

While scrolling left/right table content disappear on iOS device.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="table" class="table table-condensed table-font-size js-dynamitable" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">sadasdad</td>
                <td colspan="6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 10%;">abcdef</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 10%;">abcd</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 16%;">abjdhsadja</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 7%;">dasdsada</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 7%;">daasdasd</th>   
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 7%;">dasda</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 9%;">dasdada</th>
                <th class="sortStyle" style="width: 12%;">dasda</th>
                <th style="width: 5%;">dasdda</th>
                <th style="width: 8%;">dasda</th>
                <th class="ClsAction" style="width: 4%;"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- input filter -->
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value=""></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="4"></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="4"></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="2"></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" maxlength="7"></td>
                <td><input class="js-filter  form-control input-sm" type="text" value=""></td>                               
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="ClsAction"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="divCablelist">                                    
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The below code defines my table having filtering and sorting option.
  **Scenario: While filtering data in iOS device if I scroll / swipe table disappears.**

[IOS Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZRdVIVdlUnL8C15tEcgG7s09bdnJxcwd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please more elaborate with your code BTW link is not displaying.

Comment: I have added my code to scenario can someone help me, please